Assessing Random Search Cross Validation: Tuning in ElasticNet with Large Feature Sets
I'm working on estimating an ElasticNet model for a large dataframe with over 100,000 variables, resulting in a well overidentified scenario. To tune my model, I've set up a grid of hyperparameters (alpha and l1 ratio) ensuring it covers combinations from fully dense to completely sparse models, totaling 10,100 possible combinations.
Given the impracticality of exhaustive grid search, I opted for Randomized Search Cross Validation with 1,000 randomly chosen hyperparameter combinations. My concern now is assessing whether 1,000 randomly selected combinations out of the total 10,100 are sufficient to provide a reliable understanding of how the model performs across the hyperparameter space. Are there any established rules of thumb, theoretical guidelines, or simulations that can guide me in determining this?
Addition: Bayesian optimizing would be probably an approach that would make even more sense. However, I lack the expertise to implement that in Python for an ElasticNet model. Can anyone help?
Code Example:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV, TimeSeriesSplit
from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNet
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Generate synthetic data (simulating your data_complete and y)
np.random.seed(42)
data_complete = np.random.rand(300, 100000)  # 300 observations, 100000 variables
y = np.random.rand(300)  # 300 observations for the target variable

# Define grid of hyperparameters
params = {
    'alpha': np.logspace(-5, 5, 100, endpoint=True),  # 100 values between e^-5 and e^5
    'l1_ratio': np.append(np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.01), 1.0)  # 101 values between 0 and 1, including 1.0
}

# Create an instance of the Elastic Net Regressor
regressor = ElasticNet()

# TimeSeriesSplit cross-validation
tscv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5)  # Adjust the number of splits as needed

# Randomized Search Cross Validation
rs_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(regressor, params, n_iter=1000, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=tscv, verbose=1, n_jobs=4)
rs_cv.fit(data_complete, y)

# Optimal hyperparameters
best_params = rs_cv.best_params_
best_alpha = best_params['alpha']
best_l1_ratio = best_params['l1_ratio']

print(f"Best alpha: {best_alpha}")
print(f"Best l1_ratio: {best_l1_ratio}")

# Fit the model with the best hyperparameters
best_enet = ElasticNet(alpha=best_alpha, l1_ratio=best_l1_ratio, random_state=42)
best_enet.fit(data_complete, y)

# Evaluate the model performance
y_pred = best_enet.predict(data_complete)
mse = mean_squared_error(y, y_pred)
print(f"Final Mean Squared Error: {mse}")

